# Typescript :How to convert array of a object to another object with some of similar fields

Tags: typescript

I have two object

```
class Student{
name:string;
rollNo:number;
address:string;
city:string;
phone:string
}

class User{
name:string;
rollNo:number;
}
```

I am using this to convert array of student to user such that all same property auto maps but its not working

```
arrayOfStudent:Student[] 

User[]= arrayOfStudent as User[]
```

Comment: As far as typescript is concerned, a `Student` is **already** a `User`.  You can use a `Student` anywhere that a `User` is required.  No conversion is necessary.  https://tsplay.dev/w626rw  What is that actual goal here?  And how are you constructing these objects to ensure that all properties are set?  Based on the code here `Student` and `User` should just be an `interface` instead of a `class`.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
class User{
  name:string;
  rollNo:number;
}

class Student extends User{
  address:string;
  city:string;
  phone:string;
}

const arrayOfStudents: Student[] = <your array here>;
const arrayOfUsers = arrayOfStudents as User[];
```

Bear in mind that you will be treating the students as User, but they will keep all the Student fields.

To get rid of the extra fields you could implement a method in the Student class to convert a Student to a User:

```
class Student extends User{
  address:string;
  city:string;
  phone:string;

  asUser(): User {
    return {
      name: this.name,
      rollNo: this.rollNo
    };
  }
}
```

Then map the array of students like this:

```
const arrayOfUsers = arrayOfStudents.map(student => student.asUser());
```

Comment: no i dont want that is there any other approach?

Comment: You could try creating a method on the Student class to map the student as an User, then map the whole array. Let me update the answer...